# Laravel 5.1: sendOutputTo() truncating log file?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

When using the task scheduler in Laravel 5.1 I am redirecting command output to a log file.  It is working as expected except for the fact that it is truncating the log file before it writes, every time.

This does not for a very useful log file make.

```
$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . "/logs/mail.log");
```

I can't find anything about preventing this truncation in the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_sendOutputTo).

Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this with Event class.
This will help:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . "/logs/mail.recent");
File::append(storage_path() . "/logs/mail.log", File::get(storage_path() . "/logs/mail.recent"));
```

Not very beautifull but the only way as i know.
Also dont forget to add `use File;` to the top

Comment: Beautiful?  No.   But it is a clever solution.  Thanks for the heads up, I'll try this out if I can't find anything better.

Comment: Ended up using this, works great.  One thing of note though is you'll have to use "\File" instead of just "File" to reference the global namespace, as the File facade isn't available in whatever namespace those queue processes reside.

Comment: mb. i saw File in aliases

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.3 they added the option appendOutputTo() who does the job. Much easier :)

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')
     ->daily()
     ->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```

see it in documentation [appendOutputTo in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#task-output)